# Retaining wall on a sloped backyard won't dry

Tags: landscaping

I have a sloped back yard. The ground is saturated in front of the retaining wall. I used rock landscaping material and the water is not leaking from the wall. We have had a lot of rain and I've got sod down in this area but it is mushy and muddy. It doesn't seem to dry.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement!  A picture of the area might help people understand the situation.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'd need more info to help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: A picture would help, but it sounds to me like the grading isn't allowing water to drain away from the area.

Comment: It sounds like the wall needs weep holes to allow the moisture to drain.